# Java syntax query

Tags: java, syntax

I am getting back into java after a few yrs with .NET and I am confused about the following syntax. 
What exactly is this method expected to return in plain english?
I thought it might be a List instance composed of CategoryProxy objects. But this is not correct.
Can anyone explain what exactly it returns?

```
@Override
public Request<List<CategoryProxy>> queryCategorys() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns a `Request<List<CategoryProxy>>`.  In other words, it returns a `Request<T>` where `T` is parameterised as `List<CategoryProxy>`.  I can't tell you any more than that without knowing more about what a `Request<T>` or a `CategoryProxy` is.

Answer (score 2):

It's a `Request` parameterized with `List`, which is itself parameterized with `CategoryProxy` (google "generics").

The meaning of the parameter depends on the parameterized class. For instance, for `List` is means the type they can hold, but it can mean other things. The important point is that if a class is parameterized with a certain type, it can constrain method return and parameter types and types of fields with the parameter type.